# Can I get working code for Facebook logout?

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am not able to find the correct XPath for clicking on Logout in Facebook.
I have been trying for so long to take XPath to click on Logout.
Can anyone please help me out to click on Logout using selenium webdriver with java.

Code trials:

```
//clicking on navigation bar
driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
System.out.println("Successfully clicked");
//Clicking on logout
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Log out')]")).click();
//closing the current tab
driver.close();
```

Comment: You should share relevant HTML Block.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any exception ? like NosuchElement exception or element not found error something like that.
If so, you could wait until the element is visible and then you have to perform the operation.

```
public void test_01_Logout()
{
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.navigate().to("www.facebook.com");   
//Add login code here.
waitForElementInDOM(driver, "//div[@id='userNavigationLabel' and 
contains(text(),'Account Settings')]", 15);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='userNavigationLabel' and 
contains(text(),'Account Settings')]")).click();
waitForElementInDOM(driver, "//span[@class='54nh' and contains(text(),'Log Out')]", 
15);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='54nh' and contains(text(),'Log 
Out')]")).click();
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

public void waitForElementInDOM(WebDriver driver,String elementIdentifier, long 
timeOutInSeconds) 
{       
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds );
try
{           
//this will wait for element to be visible for 15 seconds       
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath
(elementIdentifier))); 
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{           
e.printStackTrace();
}           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Logout** you need to use *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following lines of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#userNavigationLabel")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-gt, 'menu_logout')]/span/span[normalize-space()='Log Out']"))).click();
```